# Suse 10: svnserve exit with signal 11 and hangs

Tags: linux, svn, process, sles, zombie

We are using svn (1.6.3)+sasl integration. After installationon on Suse 10.x (64 bits) I found that svnserve hanged sessions ("ps ax" shows more and more hanged svnserve processes). Xinetd logs contains a lot of lines like this

> EXIT: svn signal=11 duration=1(sec)

Svn "make check" shows that all stages passed as "success".

Does anybody try to resolve similar issue?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Signal 11 on Unix-like systems is SIGSEGV, or "Segmentation fault".

Comment: Did you install from source or pre-compiled packages?

Comment: I compile svn from the source code. I found similar issue here and try to recompile svn with native arp, but w/o success - http://linuxadminzone.com/fix-subversion-svn-child-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-error-in-apache/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Founded workaround:
daily (cron.daily)

```
/usr/bin/killall svnserve
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable core dumping by calling:

```
ulimit -c 9999999999
```

then start svnserve and let it crash (signal 11). You should find a core dump in the directory where you were as svnserve started. Load the core dump using gdb:

```
gdb --core=core svnserve
```

where "core" ist the file name of the core dump. gdb should spit out the function where the crash happend. If you need more information execute the "bt" gdb command. This will give you a back trace of the call. Probably you could guess than where the problem is.

If you don't see anything usefull just memory addresses. Try to recompile with debug switches "-g" and optimisation switches turned off "-O0".